Desktop Sharing not working Ubuntu 24.04
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04, but now I am having some difficulties trying to connect with Desktop Sharing from Windows Computer. If I try to to activate Desktop Sharing and Remote control, first it will disable "xrdp" which by turning "Desktop Sharing and Remote control" off and on again and rebooting works againenter image description hereenter image description here. Then if I try to connect from another computer again in Ubuntu I get "IBus should be called from the desktop session in Wayland" notification and the connection will be closed. I really wonder if someone else faced similar issue ? I have attached a picture enter image description here
